# IBM Websphere Liberty Profile:How to map Public IP Address in Websphere

Tags: websphere, websphere-liberty

I am trying to map my server public ip addresss in Websphere LP server.xml file but when i tried to access it from outside i am getting a connection error. I tried giving host="localhost" and tried to access from server itself,it is working fine.

Is there anything i need to configure in Websphere LP to access it from outside.

Server.xml file

```
<server description="new server">

    <!-- Enable features -->
    <featureManager>
        <feature>jsp-2.2</feature>
        <feature>localConnector-1.0</feature>
    </featureManager>

    <httpEndpoint host="*" httpPort="8007" httpsPort="9443" id="defaultHttpEndpoint"/>



    <applicationMonitor updateTrigger="mbean"/>


    <library id="worklight-6.0.0">
        <fileset dir="C:\IBM\Liberty\usr\shared\resources" includes="worklight-jee-library-6.0.0.jar"/>
    </library>

    <library id="apps-common">
        <fileset dir="C:\IBM\Liberty\usr\shared\resources" includes="org.hsqldb.hsqldb_2.2.5.jar"/>
    </library>

    <application context-root="/DemoApp" id="DemoApplication" location="DemoApplication.war" name="DemoApplication" type="war">
        <classloader commonLibraryRef="worklight-6.0.0,apps-common"/>
    </application>
</server>
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by "outside"? Another machine or another network? Can you access your server "by IP" from the same machine?

Comment: from another network....i cant access my server by giving my server ip from server machine.....but if i give localhost i can access...

Comment: Pls see the updated post , in Server.xml file i made <httpEndpoint host="*"  ..... >

Comment: Is your host "visible" from the the foreign machine/network? Do you have any firewall blocking the port 8007? What kind of connection error do you get?

Answer (score 5):

As per the InfoCenter document for the httpEndpoint configuration element, here: http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v8r5/topic/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.doc/autodita/rwlp_metatype_4ic.html?resultof=%22%68%74%74%70%65%6e%64%70%6f%69%6e%74%22%20#mtFile121

A hostname of * will bind to all available network interfaces - you do not need to do anything extra on the Liberty side, which I believe answers your question.

Setting the hostname to 'localhost' will mean the http endpoint is only accessible from your machine.

Using the configuration as supplied (hostName of *), this should work remotely - so it is likely a firewall issue.

You can check the /servers/yourServer/logs/messages.log file to verify which interfaces your endpoint is binding to - look for a message of the form

> WWKO0219I: TCP Channel defaultHttpEndpoint has been started and is now listening for requests on host localhost  (IPv4: 127.0.0.1) port 9080.